# ¿Es correcto o incorrecto decir “Balcanes plural”?

Tags: plurales, número-gramatical

Quiero usar un título corto del tipo

> Balcanes plural: historias, religiones y culturas.

Al ser un título no puedo dar una frase más larga (no me serviría hablar de “la península balcánica”, por ejemplo).

Mi duda radica en que (los) Balcanes es una palabra que ya está en plural. Pero “Balcanes plurales” no solo es una expresión cacofónica sino que, además, tiene un sentido distinto. Entiendo que al escribir “Balcanes plural” uso una forma sintética de una expresión más larga que sería “los Balcanes son una realidad plural”.

Comment: Mmmm interesante pregunta! ¿Podrías indicar un ejemplo algo largo de dónde querrías utilizar la frase? Con más contexto lo mismo nos iluminamos. Y sí, ciertamente los Balcanes son una de las zonas más plurales que conozco!

Comment: Es solo un título. Es decir, no puedo dar una frase más larga. El título completo sería así: “Balcanes plural: historias, religiones y culturas”. Sin embargo, pienso que no es un caso único. Creo que se debe poder usar correctamente la misma forma en otros casos: Estados Unidos plural, Emiratos Árabes plural.

Comment: Vale, entiendo. Añadí algo de tu comentario en la publicación original para que sirva de referencia también.

Comment: Y ya que eres nuevo en el sitio y ya vas teniendo respuestas, te animo a registrarse y a visitarnos de nuevo en el futuro : ) ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: Disculpa pero, ¿por qué consideras la expresión "Balncanes plurales"  cacofónica y en qué forma cambia el sentido de tu título? No lo veo claro.

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que tu intención es hacer un título similar a "La España plural" pero referido a los Balcanes: ✖"Balcanes plural".
Lamentablemente y como bien supones, al ser "los Balcanes" ya plural, no sería correcto aplicarle un adjetivo en singular. Tampoco sería correcto suprimir el artículo para usar "Balcanes" como nombre singular, pues no está reconocido como tal ni establecido así su uso: los nombres usados son "península balcánica", "península de los Balcanes" o, por abreviar, "los Balcanes".

Así pues, **no sería correcta, gramáticamente hablando, la expresión "Balcanes plural"**, ni otras similares como ✖"Balcanes libre" en las que se combinan un sustantivo en plural con un adjetivo en singular. Sí que serían correctas en inglés, por ejemplo, donde no existe la concordancia en número entre adjetivo y sustantivo.

---

Me gustaría, además de responder a tu pregunta, ofrecerte una alternativa gramáticamente válida... pero la verdad es que no es fácil, puesto que el gancho del título está precisamente en la palabra "plural". Se me ocurren alternativas que juegan un poco con el doble sentido, como *Balcanes se escribe en plural* o *Balcanes (plural)*. O, ya alejándonos más de tu idea original, *Pluralidad balcánica*.

De todas maneras, **que no sea gramaticalmente correcto no quiere decir que no puedas usarlo como título**. A mí particularmente no me echaría para atrás encontrarme un libro con un título así: lo entendería como una **licencia literaria** del autor para darle un mayor efecto al título.

Quién sabe: quizá, gracias a ti, empiece a establecerse el uso de "Balcanes" como nombre singular para el territorio de la antigua Yugoslavia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus luces.

Comment: Yo siempre he visto usar "los Balcanes", con artículo, ¿pero sería posible que sin el artículo se pueda usar como singular igual que pasa con Estados Unidos? Del [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=4EWtRO1VZD6v7sHSpo): *Si se emplea sin artículo, el verbo va en singular: «Estados Unidos está preparado para abrir negociaciones»*